# How to fluent-map this (using fluent nhibernate)?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, domain-driven-design, entity

I have two tables in my database "Styles" and "BannedStyles". They have a reference via the ItemNo. Now styles can be banned per store. So if style x is banned at store Y then its very possible that its not banned at store Z or vice verse. What is the best way now to map this to a single entity? Should I be mapping this to a single entity?

My Style entity looks like this:

```
public class Style
{
        public virtual int ItemNo { get; set;}
        public virtual string SKU { get; set; }
        public virtual string StyleName { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual Store Store { get; set; }
        public virtual bool IsEntireStyleBanned { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/tree/master/src/Examples.FirstProject/
might help you.

Magesh